# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object on ::first()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Ok so I'm getting `Trying to get property of non-object` when I try and get the data from the DB using `$settings = AdminSettings::first();`

here is the controller code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminSettings;

use App\AdminSettings\AdminSettings;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminSettingsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $settings = AdminSettings::first();

        return view('admins.settings.settings', compact('settings'));
    }
}
```

here is the modal code

```
    <?php

namespace App\AdminSettings;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdminSettings extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'site_settings';
    protected $fillable = [
        'site_title', 'site_url', 'email_from', 'email_to', 'timezone', 'date_format', 'time_format',
    ];
}
```

here I'm trying to put the `site_title into the input but I get Trying to get property of non-object`

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="site_title" class="form-label">Site Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="site_title" id="site_title" value="{{ $settings->site_title }}"/>
                    </div>
```

when I try to `dd($settings);` i get `null`

Comment: Are you sure, there is a record in the table?

Comment: @commonsense no I made sure the table is empty because the user could add the settings once they visit the page and click save changes and then add the settings to the DB I'm just trying to display the `{{ $settings->tsite_title }} once the user adds the data

Comment: If the table is empty, `first()` will be null, so attempting to access data on it won't work. Simple as that. Check for the existence of a setting record before attempting to use it.

Comment: @ceejayoz oh ok because i remember doing something like this before

Comment: I would use a seeder which creates the first record with basic data.

Comment: I think your table does not contain data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've said the table is empty, so make settings object [`optional`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional):

```
{{ optional($settings)->site_title }}
```

Comment: I didn't know `optional()` helper existed. Sweet!

Comment: I'm getting `Call to undefined function optional() `

Comment: `@$settings->site_title` use it that way instead

Comment: @Yosef it's available in 5.5. If you're on 5.4 and below, you can do this `{{ $settings ? $settings->site_title : '' }}`

Comment: Ok thanks, I just saw that it was only for 5.5 and i'm still on 5.4

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexeyMezenin this 'optional()' really saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or` operator too:

```
{{ $settings->site_title or ''  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [find()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) to get a single collection

```
$settings = AdminSettings::find($id);
```

You can use `first` too.

```
 $settings = AdminSettings::where('id',$id)->first();
```

And if you need entire collection then use [all()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-models)

```
$settings = AdminSettings::all();
```

In your view, make a simple check with-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="site_title" id="site_title" value="<?php echo ($settings)?$settings->site_title:'' >"/>
```

Comment: First is going to take one collection whether you set a where or not

Answer (score 0):

use empty to check object:

```
@if(!empty($settings->site_title))
  {{ $settings->site_title }}
@else
  "Nothing"
@endif
```