# Laravel 5.8: Trying to get property 'prd_name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am working on a Laravel 5.8 project which is an Online Store. and in this project, I wanted to add "Printing Order Factors" feature for Admins.

So I have made a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.newprint') }}">
    @csrf
    @forelse($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->status_label }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_total }}</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">No order to show</td>
    @endforelse
</form>
```

So basically admins can select multiple orders like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to send order ids as an array:

`<input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">`

Then at the Controller I have added this:

```
if(!empty($request->input('orderCheck'))) {
    $args = [];
    $orders = $request->input('orderCheck');
    foreach ($orders as $ord) {
        $order = Order::find($ord);
        $args[] = [
            'order' => $order,
            'address' => $order->order_address->first(),
            'details' => $order->orderDetail,
            'sendType' => $order->productSubmit,
            'coupons' => $this->cartController->computeDiscountForOutRequests($order->ord_object_id, $order->ord_creator_id),
            'user' => User::query()->find($order->ord_creator_id)
        ];
    }
    view('admin.shop.orders.printfactors', compact('args'));
}else{
    return back();
}
```

And finally at the Blade `printfactors.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($args as $arg)
    ...
    @forelse($arg['details'] as $detail)
        {{ $detail->product->prd_name }}
    @empty
    @endforelse
@endforeach
```

But I get this error:

**Trying to get property 'product' of non-object (View: printfactors.blade.php)**

So how to solve this?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks.

Here is the result of `dd($detail)`:

[image]

Comment: Try dumping $detail so you know if it is an array, and you can find out what you can echo

Comment: @GertB I just added an update on `dd($detail)` and it's not empty

Comment: since it is in a loop, it could be null in one of the items. wrap the echo in a if($detail) and maybe add a else to debug

Comment: @GertB. Please would u tell me how to print details info in proper way

Comment: The proper way would be starting with one query using whereIn() rather then multiple queries. (just a tip ) the if statement i suggested should fix your problem.

Comment: There are so many duplicates here, even just searching for your error msg shows them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382543/laravel-check-if-relation-is-empty, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714591/php-how-to-catch-a-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118327/laravel-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-on-first, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668889/how-to-solve-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-laravel ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your information it looks like `$arg['details']` is not coming empty and when fetching relation `product` in loop, one of the value of `$detail` is coming as `null`.

Try debugging for each order, what is the value of `$arg['details']`.

Comment: Same result as the picture of `dd($detail)` shows

Comment: @KKKKKK try using the [optional function link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional)  to see which value caused the issue. `{{ optional($detail)->product->prd_name }}`

Comment: I tried `{{ optional($detail)->product->prd_name }}` but still shows the error

Comment: @KKKKKK use the nested optional to see if product is coming null as well. `{{optional(optional($detail)->product)->prd_name }}`